# How can I return my nav bar to normal after using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I followed [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) tutorial to create a responsive nav bar, but I modified a large part of the code to use a flexbox instead of floats and used less nav items than the tutorial. My only issue so far is that if I resize to 480px or less, open the nav menu, and then resize to larger than 480px, the nav menu will stay displaying as a block instead of returning to flex. I believe this is due to the jquery I used, but I'm not as familiar with jquery as I'd have to be to track down this bug.

What do I have to do so that if you resize while the navigation bar has been toggled, the navigation items return to `display: flex;` instead of staying with `display:block;`?

Below is a fiddle of my work and if you need more information, please ask.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshbsx0L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove `&& menu.is(':hidden')` from

```
if (w > 480 && menu.is(':hidden')) 
{
   menu.removeAttr('style');
}
```

and it should work as expected.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cshbsx0L/1/)

Comment: Wow, Thanks! This worked for me. Can you explain why the ```&& menu.is(':hidden')``` was preventing it from returning to normal?